# Establishing IPV6 socket connection using CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, cfsocket

Im facing issue for creating a socket connection with an iPV6 using CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost.
But I'm able to create socket connection with IPV4 for the same port number.

Tried with all scenarios like adding http, https without http, adding  between IPV6 address, 
Nothing worked for me.

The output coming for IPV6 is 
stream event 8 (Error code is 8)
Ending up with NSStreamEventErrorOccurred in handleEvent method
Below is the code, i used to create socket connection

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
NSString *url = [@"[fe80::fe15:b4ff:feb7:102a]" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//    NSString *url = @"13.61.14.130";
NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)myUrl.path, 82, &readStream, &writeStream);

inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];




-(void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {

    NSLog(@"stream event %i", streamEvent);
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u",streamEvent] message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"stream event %i", streamEvent] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
    switch (streamEvent) {

        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            NSLog(@"Stream opened");
            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

            if (theStream == inputStream) {

                uint8_t buffer[1024];
                int len;

                while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                    len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                    if (len > 0) {

                        NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                        if (nil != output) {

                            NSLog(@"server said: %@", output);
                            [self messageReceived:output];

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;


        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:

            NSLog(@"Can not connect to the host!");
            break;

        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:

            [theStream close];
            [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            [theStream release];
            theStream = nil;

            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Unknown event");
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use the [tag:xcode] tag unless you have an issue with the IDE itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `[]` before the IPV6 and use this format :

```
NSString *url = [@"fe80::fe15:b4ff:feb7:102a" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Hopefully this should work.